# Include class usning psr4 autoload vs includ class using namespace in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I am using laravel. I created `Orders` folder in `app` directory and created class `Payments`.
I added that class by `namespace` into my `controller` (by using phpstorm suggestions) and It worked fine.

Now my question is why do we use `composer psr-4 autoload` if we can add classes directly using namespace?
Following is composer psr-4 autoload example

```
"psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Orders\\": "app/Orders",
        }
```

Now what is the benifit of adding my module folder in psr-4 autoload because I can add classes without psr-4 autoload?

Comment: PSR autoloading is what maps classes and their namespaces to files. So although you imported the class in your controller, PSR is how PHP figured out where the code lived

Comment: This is the confusion that what is the benifit of using PSR autoloading if we can load class using namespace directly?

Comment: Namespaces do not load anything. Period. If PHP tries to load a class that does not exist it calls the defined autoloaders. If a PSR4-compatible autoloader has been defined then it uses its base directory and the namespace to determine where the file containing the class _should_ be, and loads that file. I am not familiar with Laravel, but it's possible that it has its own autoloader aside from Composer's, or that you've written your code/config in such a way that it _seems_ like you don't need to change the autoloader config in Composer.

Comment: "I can add classes without psr-4 autoload" - what do you mean by that? Do you want to edit the composer.json for each and every class you add to your application?